# Can we show that the characteristic function of an infinitely divisible probability measure has no zeros

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, convolution, levy-processes, infinite-divisibility

Let $E$ be a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space, $\mu$ be a probability measure on $\mathcal B(E)$ and $\varphi_\mu$ denote the characteristic function$^1$ of $\mu$.

Assume $\mu$ is *infinitely divisible*, i.e. there is a sequence $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of probability measures on $\mathcal B(E)$ such that$^2$ $$\mu=\mu_n^{\ast n}\tag1$$ and hence $$\varphi_\mu=\varphi_{\mu_n}^n\tag2$$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. We can easily show that$^3$ $$\left|\varphi_\mu\right|^{\frac2n}=\left|\varphi_{\mu_n}\right|^2=\varphi_{|\mu_n|^2}\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N.\tag3$$

Let $$\varphi(x'):=\left.\begin{cases}1&\text{, if }\varphi_\mu(x')\ne0\\0&\text{, otherwise}\end{cases}\right\}\tag4\;\;\;\text{for }x'\in E'.$$ By $(3)$ and $(4)$, $$\left|\varphi_{\mu_n}\right|^2\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\varphi\tag5$$.

> By $(3)$ and $(5)$, $\left(\left|\varphi_{\mu_n}\right|^2\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence of characteristic functions convering pointwise to $\varphi$.
>
> If $E=\mathbb R^d$ for some $d\in\mathbb N$, we can immediately conclude that $\varphi$ is the characteristic function of a probability measure on $\mathcal B(E)$ by Lèvy’s continuity theorem.
>
> If $E$ is a general normed $\mathbb R$-vector space, are we able to deduce the same result using the Itō-Nisio theorem$^4$? If not, can we come up with a different approach which yields this result at least in the particular case of a separable $\mathbb R$-Banach space?

> **Remark**: Note that my actual goal is to deduce that an infinitely divisible probabilty measures $\mu$ on $\mathcal B(E)$ satisfies $\varphi_\mu(x')\ne0$ for all $x'\in E'$. The conclusion I've asked for above is obviously sufficient to obtain this result; but it clearly is not necessary, so there might be a better approach for this.

---

$^1$ i.e. $$\varphi_\mu(x'):=\int\mu({\rm d}x)e^{{\rm i}\langle x,\:x'\rangle}\;\;\;\text{for }x'\in E'.$$

$^2$ If $\nu_1,\ldots,\nu_k$ are measures on $\mathcal B(E)$ and $$\theta_k:E^k\to E\;,\;\;\;x\mapsto x_1+\cdots+x_k,$$ then the *convolution* of $\nu_1,\ldots,\nu_k$ is defined to be the pushforward measure $$\nu_1\ast\cdots\ast\nu_k:=\theta_k(\nu_1\otimes\cdots\otimes\nu_k)$$ of the product measure $\nu_1\otimes\cdots\otimes\nu_k$ with respect to $\theta_k$. If $\nu_1=\cdots=\nu_k$, we simply write $\nu_1^{\ast k}:=\nu_1\ast\cdots\ast\nu_k$.

$^3$ If $\nu$ is a finite measure on $\mathcal B(E)$, then $$\nu^-(B):=\nu(-B)\;\;\;\text{for }B\in\mathcal B(E)$$ and $$|\nu|^2:=\nu\ast\nu^-.$$

$^4$ Itō-Nisio theorem: Let $\nu_n,\nu$ be tight (hence Radon) probability measures on $\mathcal B(E)$ such that $\nu_n$ is symmetric (i.e. $\nu_n=\nu_n^-$), $\nu_n\prec\nu_{n+1}$ (i.e. there is a probability measure $\sigma_n$ such that $\nu_{n+1}=\nu_n\ast\sigma$) and $\varphi_{\nu_n}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\varphi_\nu$, then $(\nu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\to\nu$ in the topology of [weak convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures) of measures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand\vpi\varphi\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$

1. The approach involving (4) will not work, because [Lévy's continuity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%27s_continuity_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20probability%20theory%2C%20L%C3%A9vy%27s%20continuity,convergence%20of%20their%20characteristic%20functions.) will guarantee that the pointwise limit of characteristic functions (c.f.'s) is a c.f. only when the limit function function is continuous (everywhere or, equivalently, at the origin).
2. Nonetheless, your c.f. $\vpi_\mu$ is nonzero everywhere. Indeed, for any $x'\in E'$ and any real $t$,
   $$\vpi_\mu(tx')=\int_E\mu(dx)\,e^{itx'(x)}=\vpi_{x'\sharp\mu}(t),\tag{1}$$
   where $\vpi_{x'\sharp\mu}$ is the c.f of the probability measure $x'\sharp\mu$ over $\R$ that is the pushforward of $\mu$ under the map $x'$. The probability measure $x'\sharp\mu$ over $\R$ is infinitely divisible, since $\mu$ is infinitely divisible: if $\mu=\mu_n^{*n}$, then $x'\sharp\mu=(x'\sharp\mu_n)^{*n}$. So, by the  [Lévy--Khintchine formula](https://people.cam.cornell.edu/av395/levy-khintchine.pdf), $\vpi_{x'\sharp\mu}(t)\ne0$ for all real $t$. (Instead of the Lévy--Khintchine formula, it suffices to use e.g. [Theorem 1 in Section 1 of Chapter XVII of Feller, Vol. II, Second Ed.](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/An+Introduction+to+Probability+Theory+and+Its+Applications%2C+Volume+2%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9780471257097))
   Taking now $t=1$ in (1), we get $\vpi_\mu(x')\ne0$ for all $x'\in E'$, as desired.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Regarding 1: The limit function in question, i.e. $\varphi$ defined in $(4)$, *is* continuous at the origin. The problem with Lévy's continuity theorem is that it only holds for measures on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d$), $d\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: Regarding 2: How do you prove the Lévy-Khintchine formula without already knowing that the characteristic function of an infinite divisible measures has no zeros? It is actually my intent to prove the Lévy-Khintchine formula in the setting of the question and the problem described in my post is one problem which I've encountered in generalization the usual proof. Do you've got another idea how we can see the desired claim without the Lévy-Khintchine formula? Don't you think the Ito-Nisio theorem could be applied, for example?

Comment: @0xbadf00d : I have added a detail on how to get the desired no-zeroes conclusion using only an intermediate result in a proof of the Lévy-Khintchine formula.

Comment: @0xbadf00d : As for the Ito-Nisio theorem, it is essentially about the convergence in distribution of a **series** of independent **symmetric** random vectors to a random vector -- rather than about a **triangular array** of iid (in each row of the array) independent **not necessarily symmetric** random vectors, as in your case. So, I do not see any possible relevance of the Ito-Nisio theorem to your question.

Comment: [Previous comment continued:] Anyhow, by the virtue of the above answer, your "actual goal", "to deduce that an infinitely divisible probabilty measures $\mu$ on $\mathcal B(E)$ satisfies $\varphi_\mu(x')\ne0$ for all $x'\in E'$", is now attained. It is also explained why the other approaches will not work.